# Load Balancer is not accessible outside cluster

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes, k3s

I have setup 3 master and 6 worker nodes using the same IP segment, 172.26.10.XX.

For load balancer services, I'm using Kube-Vip for load balancer with configuration namespace specifics as below: -

```
Data
====
cidr-private-app:
----
172.26.10.XX/27
range-global:
----
172.26.16.XX-172.26.16.XX
range-public-app:
----
172.26.14.XX-172.26.14.XX

BinaryData
```

When I try to expose a service LB with IP 172.26.10.XX, I can access the in/out cluster with no problem. But when I come to expose a service with LB IPs 172.26.16.XX and 172.26.14.XX, I can access them only in the cluster nodes and not outside the cluster. Something wrong? All the advice is appreciated.

Noted:

K8S: v1.27.7+k3s2 KUBE-VIP: 0.6.4 Firewall rules : Allow/All communication server to server with Ips segment 172.26.10.XX, 172.26.16.XX and 172.26.14.XX

Restart all node and checking configuration firewall.

I'm expecting the LB can surf IP address with difference IP segment.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

172.26.16.0 is a different subnet than 172.26.10.0/27. Hosts inside the cluster will have routing information for the 172.26.16.0 subnet since kube-vip adds the correct routes. Hosts outside the cluster will not know where to find this subnet unless specifically told (something is updating their routes). For hosts missing a route, they'll use the default route which is generally a router on the network. If that router doesn't know where to find 172.26.16.0 it will either drop the packets or route them out *its* default route.

When you use an IP inside the subnet the hosts are configured with, other hosts will see they're sending information to a host in the same network and they'll use ARP to look up the MAC address of the destination and send frames to that host.

You can examine these routing tables on nodes inside and outside the cluster

```
ip route show table all
```

tldr; you need a router to cross between networks. Your Kubernetes nodes are acting as routers so that's why communication works from inside the cluster

## Solution

Probably easiest is to use IPs that are part of the host subnet if you want hosts outside the cluster to be able to reach the IPs. For instance, if your hosts are in subnet 172.26.10.0/27, use 172.26.10.24/29 (.24 - .31) for your VIPs.

Another option; setup static routes on hosts outside Kubernetes that tell them they can find the VIP network using the Kubernetes nodes as a gateway. If your nodes are 172.26.10.1, .2, .3, then hosts outside k8s would have a route like `172.26.16.0/24 via 172.26.10.1`

Another option; setup routes on the router hosts outside k8s use and have the router send traffic to the VIP network back out (your router will probably need an IP address for each subnet configured on the same interface)

Another option; add secondary IPs to each host outside k8s that's in the same subnet as the load balancer VIPs.

Another option; setup a routing protocol like RIP or OSPF so hosts outside k8s can learn about networks inside the k8s cluster (some CNIs do this like Calico w/ BGP)